# Dynamically added button throwing error

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, button, addition

I'm trying to dynamically add a button like so:

```
contentPlaceHolder cp = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("mainPageContent");
.
.
.
Button b = new Button();
b.ID = "btn" + tpnl.ClientID;
b.CssClass = "hiddenBtn";
b.CommandName = tpnl.ID;
b.Command += btnTrigger_Click;
cp.Controls.Add(b);
```

Now this **should** add my button to the placeholder (which is in a master page). I can get the content placeholder and manipulate it just fine in other areas in the code.
The problem is the buttons throw a "Control of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server" error.

I can't figure out why it's doing this - I can add other controls to the placeholder just fine in other parts of the code.

Comment: Can you give a more complete example of the code specific to the button not working and an example of the code specific to where you are able to successfully add a control to the ContentPlaceHolder? Can you also include in what events the code is executing?

Comment: Right now this is executing in Page_Init.

Comment: Have you verified that cp isn't null?

Comment: Yes, CP has a value in this case. It's the content placeholder on a master page.

The funny thing is when I run this code in a page not using a masterpage it's fine.